# How to attach a corner shelf to the shower tile

Tags: repair, shower, adhesive, shelf

The (ceramic) corner shelf in my shower is starting to detach from the porcelain tile. What kind of adhesive should I use to reattach it? I don't want to make any holes in the wall. The shelf is fairly light - approximately 8" radius.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming to can arrange to hold it in place for a while (test your method before applying adhesive) clear silicone caulking would to the trick. It holds glass fish tanks together all by itself.

Get everything very clean first, and leave it held in place and undisturbed for at least 24 hours, preferably avoiding putting weight on it for a couple of days.

Comment: I've used blocks of wood held with duct tape as a support. Be careful you don't get any silicone on the wood or you'll end up gluing the wood to the soap dish.

Comment: For the OP: "very clean" means removing all signs of the old, failing adhesive. Putting new adhesive on old stuff that's falling off means that the new stuff will be well attached to the old stuff when it falls off.